# How can I make a sticky navbar without position: fixed

Tags: html, css

I have an `HTML` template and I need to make his left sidebar fixed (no scrolling) without using `position: fixed` because it ruins all the template.

[image: Desired Output]

```
<div class="layout-w">

    <!-- menu -->
    <div class="menu">
         <!-- elements here -->
    </div>

    <!-- content -->
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Elements here -->
    </div>

</div>
```

And this the css

```
.layout-w {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This may help you. [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 2):

You could just put your menu div inside another div with height of 100% and background-color:transparent.

```
<div class="layout-w">

<!-- menu -->
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="menu">
     <!-- elements here -->
     </div>
</div>


<!-- content -->
<div class="content">
    <!-- Elements here -->
</div>
```

and in css file:

```
.menu-container { height: 100%; background-color: transparent; }
.menu { postion: fixed }
```

Comment: or you could use this code: https://codepen.io/ABawer/pen/OJJoEKK

Comment: In the end I used the position fixed on the menu but I added a margin-left to the content and it's fine.